# How to send a $_SESSION varible through cUrl

Tags: php, curl, session-variables

Hello im trying to send a $_SESSION varible through cUrl.
What I have is a site made by myself:

The site is like a book you write a post and then it gets saved in a .txt file and updated onto the site and displayed.

[My website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOb0K.jpg)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $firstnumb = rand(0, 10);
    $secondnumb = rand(0, 10);
    $_SESSION['answer'] = $firstnumb + $secondnumb;
?>
```

(junk code between)

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Post message</legend>
    <form action="postmsg.php" method="post">
            <div class="box">
                    <h3>Lable:</h3>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Lable" name="lable" value="<?php print $_SESSION['lable'];?>"/>
                    <h3>Name:</h3>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" value="<?php print $_SESSION['name'];?>"/>
                    <h3>Email:</h3>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="<?php print $_SESSION['email'];?>"/>
                    <h3>Website:</h3>
                    <input type="url" placeholder="Url" name="website" value="<?php print $_SESSION['url'];?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                    <h3>Message</h3>
                    <textarea rows="6" cols="22" placeholder="Write a message" name="msg"><?php print $_SESSION['msg']; ?></textarea>
                    <h3><?php echo $firstnumb." + ".$secondnumb." ? "; ?></h3>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Captcha" name="captcha" value="<?php print $_SESSION['captcha'];?>"/>

                    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
            </div>
    </form>
```

What I want to do is try to make a message spammer and to prevent it later on.
But I ran into a problem, I cant seem to send $_SESSION["answer"] to the site and therefore it gets undefined. Finaly nothing gets posted.

Spam message code:

```
<?php
    require("strrand.php");

    $url = '---/postmsg.php';
    $fields = 6;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $fields);

    for($i = 0; $i < 1;$i++){
            $fieldstring = "lable=".strRand(10)."&name=".strRand(10)."&email=".strRand(10)."@".strRand(10).".".strRand(10)."&msg=".strRand(125)."&captcha=".$captcha."&website=".strRand(10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldstring);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

?>

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWyxk.png)

But I know that I can send a $_COOKIE through cUrl, but I just wondered is it possible to set info into $_SESSION["answer"] or is it impossible?

I dont want to change anything in the book code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Set your data into an array or sting. You do not need to send $_SESSION or $_COOKIE via Curl.

Do one thing;

```
$answer[] = $_SESSION; 
// Here $answer is an array. you can send array via curl.

or $answer = $_SESSION['answer'];
// Here $answer is an a variable(string). you can send it via curl.
```

Now send `$answer` via Curl.

**Suggestion**:-

> Use variables to send data to curl request or any other requests. read
>   PHP [SESSION](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm) and [COOKIE](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_cookies.htm) in detail.